# The minimal group with Fitting length three has $p$ section in middle?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with Fitting lengt $3$ i.e

$$e< F_1< F_2 < F_3=G$$ and $F(G)=F_1$ and $\bar {F_2}=F(G/F_1)$.

Assume that for every proper characteristic subgroup $K$ of $G$, Fitting length of $K$ and $G/K$ is at most $2$.

Is there any example where $F_2/F_1$ is not a $p$ group ? The intuation behind this is that both $F_1$ and $F_3/F_2$ is $p$-groups for some primes.

In that case, is it true that lower Fitting series and upper fitting series coincide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that ${\mathtt{SmallGroup}}(300,25)$ is a counterexample.

It has Fitting length $3$, with $|F_1|=25$, $|F_2/F_1|=6$ and $|F_3/F_2|=2$.

It has two normal subgroups of index $2$ with Fitting length $3$, but they are interchanged by an automorphism of $G$, so they are not characteristic.

$F_1$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup, so all proper quotients have Fitting length at most $2$.

Comment: If Gap found the example, why are you not sure ?

Comment: When I write "I think", it does not exactly mean that I am not sure. It is more a suggestion that you should check my calculations!

Comment: Ok thank you . Good example.

Comment: You do not need "!". I had thought that Gap found this example but you think it may be wrong. That is why I asked.